# Can't call the ZipArchive class

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have `ZipArchive` enabled, the PHP extension. In my class, when I run:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'LukeMadhanga\ZipArchive' not found

I am guessing the problem is how I call `ZipArchive`? Or a namespace issue?

Comment: You're calling from within the `LukeMadhanga` namespace, and ZipArchive exists in the __global__ namespace.... use `$zip = new \ZipArchive;` (and learn about [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indeed looks like a namespace issue, you need to access your `ZipArchive` class from the global namespace :

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive;
```

Comment: You got it my friend. Thank you.